# Powershell Start-Process with Splatting

Tags: powershell

I want to call a "PS App Deployment Toolkit"-package ([Link](http://psappdeploytoolkit.com/)) from a PowerShell-Script with arguments.

The mentioned "PS App Deployment Toolkit"-package is a powershell-script, which I want to call with parameters. (Call a .ps1 from a .ps1)

I want to use splatting for the parameters.
I want to wait for the script to end.
I want to get the exit-code from the script.

Here is my code, which is not working:

```
$PSADToolKitInstallWrapper = "C:\Temp\MyPackage\PS-AppDeploy.ps1"

$PSADToolKitParameters = @{
    "DeploymentType" = "Uninstall";
    "DeployMode" = "Interactive";
    "AllowRebootPassThru" = $True;
    "TerminalServerMode" = $False;
    "DisableLogging" = $False;
}        

$InstallStatus = Start-Process -FilePath "PowerShell.exe" -ArgumentList $PSADToolKitInstallWrapper @PSADToolKitParameters -Wait -PassThru

Write-Host "Exit-Code: $( $InstallStatus.ExitCode )"
```

This Line would work fine, but I want to set the Parameters like in the example above:

```
$InstallStatus = Start-Process -FilePath "PowerShell.exe" -ArgumentList "$PSADToolKitInstallWrapper","-DeploymentType Install -DeployMode Silent -AllowRebootPassThru -TerminalServerMode" -Wait -PassThru
```

Could you please assist me to get this working?

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't splatting at all in your example.  If you got rid of `@PSADToolKitParameters`, it would work

Comment: ...and @TheIncorrigible1 is correct. Your example contains no splatting. See my answer for how to use splatting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to try so hard. Why run `powershell.exe` from inside a PowerShell script? You're already running PowerShell. Just run the command line you want:

```
$PSADToolKitParameters = @{
  "DeploymentType" = "Uninstall"
  "DeployMode" = "Interactive"
  "AllowRebootPassThru" = $True
  "TerminalServerMode" = $False
  "DisableLogging" = $False
}
C:\Temp\MyPackage\PS-AppDeploy.ps1 @PSADToolKitParameters
```

If the path and/or filename to the script you want to run contains spaces, then call it with the invocation operator (`&`) and quote the filename; example:

```
& "C:\Temp\My Package\PS-AppDeploy.ps1" @PSADToolKitParameters
```

Checking the results of the script depends on what the script returns. If it returns an output object, then you can simply assign it:

```
$output = C:\Temp\MyPackage\PS-AppDeploy.ps1 ...
```

If the script runs an executable that sets an exit code, you check the value of the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable (this is analogous to the `%ERRORLEVEL%` dynamic variable in `cmd.exe`).

Comment: Just a note, he wants to capture the exit code of the script

Comment: Yes, the script gets called correctly, but I don't get an Exit-Code ...

Comment: @Walhalla If you add `$Var = & ...` you should get the whatever the script returns in the `$Var` variable.

Comment: $var ist empty :-(

Comment: Have you checked the variable `$LASTEXITCODE` after running the script?

Comment: I did just check: Run the script with "Start-Process" => Exit Code = 1  
Run the script with "&" => Exit-Code = $Null ; LastExitCode is not that what I want

Comment: As I noted in my answer: "Checking the results of the script depends on what the script returns." There is not sufficient information in your question to answer that part for you.

Comment: Won't it be possible to use "Start-Process" for this and pass the parameters as requested? With "Start-Process" it is working and I don't get headache with return-codes.

Comment: @Walhalla It's a lot more convoluted to do so and unnecessary when you're running another script.

Comment: What does "headache with return-codes" mean? Please be specific. There should be no need for `Start-Process`.